# Does Shamir Secret Sharing provide integrity?

Tags: secret-sharing, integrity

Shamir secret sharing splits into t number of shares with a t-threshold. However, I can find no information online if this scheme provide integrity (or authentication for that matter, which I assume it does not).

Can an adversary forge a share? If not, what hard problem is he faced with. Is it due to the share should be indistinguishable from random (psuedorandom)?

Comment: There are verifiable Shamir schemes in the literature. These do provide integrity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By [Lagrange interpolation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_polynomial)...

> Does Shamir Secret Sharing provide integrity?

No

> Can an adversary forge a share?

Yes